# Spring Integration Streaming Inbound channel adapter in cluster environment

Tags: spring-integration

I have a requirement to implement the sftp streaming inbound channel adapter in multi/cluster environment. I am not supposed to store the file in my local directory, i have stream the file and process it immediately.
It's working very well in single instance, but If i try to run the poller in multiple nodes am running in to issues like duplicate processing, file not found for the 2nd node.

I tried implementing it with the propertiesmetadatastore as per the docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/redis.html#redis-metadata-store
datastore is getting created but still the issue was not yet resolved.

Could some one please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not clear what's going on in your environment, but `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with any possible distributed `MetadataStore` is the solution for you. Right, `RedisMetadataStore` is one of them: all your cluster instances have to look into the same Redis server though.

Comment: Artem, I think you mean the FTP or SFTP persistent filter; we don't use the file system in the streaming adapter.

Comment: But do I need to use Redis/Memcache or will it work with the PropertiesPersisitingMetadatastore also. 
Below is my code what i am trying 'SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter filter = new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(meta(),"."); filter.setFlushOnUpdate(true);' PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore meta = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore(); meta.setBaseDirectory("/tmp"); meta.setFileName("stream.properties"); return meta;

Comment: Well, in theory if that `/tmp` file system directory is available for all instances in cluster, e.g. mounted network resource, then yes, it may work. But you need to understand that to avoid duplication, there should be something *shared* to let all the instances to look into.

Comment: @ArtemBilan

Do I need to write any information from the node to the datastore to get the file locked or is this was handled by the SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter on its own if datastore declaration exists

Comment: It is done transparently for you via `MetadataStore`. There is no file locking, but filtering. So, if there is an entry in the store for the file, it isn't going to be processed.

Comment: When you mean filtering will this requirement to implement this in clustered environment, and only one node should process one file will get resolve and 
I have list of limitations to get this implemented:
1) I have to do sftp file streaming directly from the remote server, am not supposed to store the file locally.
2) Stream the file and directly process it and drop the file in same remote server
3) I can't use redismetadatastore between two nodes also which I came to know today

Comment: Well, if you can't use Redis, you may consider to use some other implementation, or consider to use `Leader Election`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#leadership-event-handling. With the `MetadataStore` we don't download the file: we use just its name for the entry. The file won't be downloaded by the second node if the first one has already processed it and placed its name to the store.

Comment: PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore wont solve my problem as it will be working on the instance level. is my understanding correct?. In other words I mean this is not same as RedisMetadataStore like which will handle multiple nodes right?

Comment: Correct. To make a thing unique in the cluster we need to provide something shared for all nodes in cluster. Not sure why you still try to stick with `local file system`-based `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore`...

Comment: @ArtemBilan
yeah I completely agree with you with the restrictions what I have I am not able to use that RedisMetadatastore. But now I am able to make it work with the JdbcMetadataStore which is working fine.

Thanks for your help